# Is it possible to write a single regex that can grab all input from an opening delimiter to a matching closing delimiter?

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

For example, if I have the string:

*[some text[more text]]*  I would expect to get  *some text[more text]* as a match. I can guarantee the string will begin with the delimiter.

More examples of what I am looking for

*{content{deeper content{deepest content}}}* would give *content{deeper content{deepest content}}*

*(1{2(3)})* would give *1{2(3)}*

I could write a method that will do the necessary counting of opening and closing delimiters, but can it be done with a single regex? I intent to use this in flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex that will match anything between a matching pair of `( )`, `[ ]`, or `{ }`.

`(?:\(|\{|\[)(.+)(?:\)|\}|\])`

https://regex101.com/r/k2HTMe/3